# A better way to remove classes for responsive design (may be without media queries)

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, removeclass

my code works, but its not that "professional" because it has some drawbacks like it loads the page every time it resizes the browser window, but what if some one entered data(it will be gone after resizing...
The aim should be to remove some classes in the responsive design and than add them back after resizing it back to a desktop pc size.(may be it can be solved without media queries)

The code:

```
     //remove classes for responsive
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

    //to be there on page load(without resizing the browser, to get the responsive view)
    $(function () {
        if (ww < 768) {
            //alert("size" + ww);
            console.log(ww);
            $("*").removeClass("BWPaddingLeft");
            $("*").removeClass("BWPaddingRight");
            $("*").removeClass("BWTextLeft");
            $("*").removeClass("BWTextRight");
            $("*").removeClass("BWPaddingLeftRight");
            $("*").removeClass("BWOverFlowNews");
        }
    });


    $(window).resize(function () {
        var ww1 = document.body.clientWidth; //to get the current width
        if (ww1 > 767 ) {
            window.location.href = document.URL; //load the page to get the removed classes after resizing
            //Problem it will not just once..(after resizing the browser)
        }
        else {
            //removing not needed classes for responsive design
            $("*").removeClass("BWPaddingLeft");
            $("*").removeClass("BWPaddingRight");
            $("*").removeClass("BWTextLeft");
            $("*").removeClass("BWTextRight");
            $("*").removeClass("BWPaddingLeftRight");
            $("*").removeClass("BWOverFlowNews");
        }
    });
```

Ty, for helping

Comment: Why don't you use CSS media queries to define CSS rules for specific classes? Anyway, instead of checking for body clientWidth, you should use in javascript `window.matchMedia()`

Comment: because it is not supported for IE9 and less (http://caniuse.com/matchmedia)

Comment: but may be this is an option http://blog.astaz3l.com/2013/11/27/matchmedia/ ...

Comment: Instead, you should use CSS media queries and for IE8 which doesn't support it, use some kind of conditional statement. Anyway, i don't think you should have to much to worry about IE8 user on mobile device. So you shouldn't care much about responsive design for IE8 users. That's said, that really depends of what you are looking for/expecting, it's up to you ;)  As a general advice, anything regarding design should be set in CSS, not in javascript because anyway some users could have javascript disabled, so...

Comment: I worry about it because the script causes some kind of bugs like for everything less than IE9 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037023/my-script-reloads-every-time-in-ie-8-ie-7-and-lower-versions-without-stoping?noredirect=1#comment37055644_24037023)

Comment: But again, for responsive design purpose, you should use some media queries in CSS, no javascript at all. For desktop users using IE8<, just let them see a non responsive page, they're quite habit to that anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of removing classes you will replace them with other?

```
//to remove class
$(".BWPaddingLeft").removeClass("BWPaddingLeft").addClass("BWPaddingLeft-inactive"); 

//to add class again
$(".BWPaddingLeft-inactive").removeClass("BWPaddingLeft-inactive").addClass("BWPaddingLeft");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution, because it also solves that problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037023/my-script-reloads-every-time-in-ie-8-ie-7-and-lower-versions-without-stoping?noredirect=1#comment37055644_24037023) .ty :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple classname separated by space :

```
 $("*").removeClass("BWPaddingLeft  BWPaddingLeft BWTextLeft BWTextRight ...etc");
```

Comment: That's a nice improvement, but it does not solve the main problem. But thanks anyway for this hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? Store the classes in a variable and toggle it if needed.

```
//remove classes for responsive
    var css = "BWPaddingLeft BWPaddingRight BWTextLeft BWTextRight BWPaddingLeftRight BWOverFlowNews";
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

    //to be there on page load(without resizing the browser, to get the responsive view)
    $(function () {
        $("*").toggleClass(css, (ww >= 768));
    });


    $(window).resize(function () {
        var ww1 = document.body.clientWidth; //to get the current width
        if (ww1 > 767 ) {
            window.location.href = document.URL; //load the page to get the removed classes after resizing
            //Problem it will not just once..(after resizing the browser)
        }
        else {
            $("*").removeClass(css);
        }
    });
```

Comment: actually now everything is reaarranged not just the classes I wanted to change, just everthing..